# Unable to add Rows to DataGridView programically

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm have created a purchase order form and added all data to tables. now I wanted to update purchase order items by adding new items to `DataGridView`.

I have filled `DataGridView` with old items and now I wanted to add new items but it is not working

Error: Rows cannot be programmatically added to the `DataGridView` rows collection when the control is data-bound.

[image]

Here is my code which I'm using to add a new row in updateMode.

```
    try
            {
                if (updateMode)
                {
                    //DataTable dt = dataGridPOItems.DataSource as DataTable;
                    //DataRow rw = dt.NewRow();

                    //DataTable dt = dataGridPOItems.DataSource as DataTable;
                    //DataRow rw = dt.NewRow();

                    //var dataSource = dataGridPOItems.DataSource as BindingSource;
                    //var dataTable = dataSource.DataSource as DataTable;

                    DataTable dt = dataGridPOItems.DataSource as DataTable;
                    dt.Rows.Add();

                    dataGridPOItems.DataSource = dt;

                    int rowIndex = this.dataGridPOItems.RowCount;
                    var row = this.dataGridPOItems.Rows[rowIndex];

                    row.Cells["Product_ID"].Value = txtPOProdID.Text;
                    row.Cells["HSN"].Value = txtPOProdHSN.Text;
                    row.Cells["EAN"].Value = txtPOProdBarcode.Text;
                    row.Cells["PName"].Value = txtPOProdName.Text;
                    row.Cells["OrderQty"].Value = txtPOProdQtyReq.Text;
                    row.Cells["PMargin"].Value = txtPOProdMargin.Text;
                    row.Cells["MRP"].Value = txtPOProdMRP.Text;
                    row.Cells["GSTRate"].Value = txtPOProdGST.Text;

                    row.Cells["LandingCost"].Value = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["MRP"].Value) - ((Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["MRP"].Value) * Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["PMargin"].Value) / 100)), 2);

                    row.Cells["BCost"].Value = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["LandingCost"].Value) / (Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["GSTRate"].Value) / 100 + 1), 2);

                    row.Cells["BCostAmt"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["BCost"].Value) * Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["OrderQty"].Value);

                    row.Cells["GSTAmt"].Value = Math.Round((Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["BCostAmt"].Value) * (Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["GSTRate"].Value) / 100)), 2);

                    row.Cells["NetAmt"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["BCostAmt"].Value) + Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["GSTAmt"].Value);

                    txtPOProdQtyReq.Clear();

                    txtPOTotalItems.Text = Convert.ToString(rowIndex + 1);


                    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridPOItems.Columns)
                    {
                        txtPOTotalQty.Text = dataGridPOItems.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Sum(r => Convert.ToDecimal(r.Cells[4].Value)).ToString();
                        txtPOTCost.Text = dataGridPOItems.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Sum(r => Convert.ToDecimal(r.Cells[12].Value)).ToString();
                        txtPOTAX.Text = dataGridPOItems.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Sum(r => Convert.ToDecimal(r.Cells[10].Value)).ToString();

                    }

                    ClassControlsHandler.ClearAll(this.groupProdInfo);
                    txtPOProdID.Focus();


                }
                else
                {
                    int rowIndex = this.dataGridPOItems.Rows.Add();
                    var row = this.dataGridPOItems.Rows[rowIndex];

                    row.Cells["ProductID"].Value = txtPOProdID.Text;
                    row.Cells["HSN"].Value = txtPOProdHSN.Text;
                    row.Cells["EAN"].Value = txtPOProdBarcode.Text;
                    row.Cells["PName"].Value = txtPOProdName.Text;
                    row.Cells["OrderQty"].Value = txtPOProdQtyReq.Text;
                    row.Cells["PMargin"].Value = txtPOProdMargin.Text;
                    row.Cells["MRP"].Value = txtPOProdMRP.Text;
                    row.Cells["GSTRate"].Value = txtPOProdGST.Text;

                    row.Cells["LandingCost"].Value = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["MRP"].Value) - ((Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["MRP"].Value) * Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["PMargin"].Value) / 100)), 2);

                    row.Cells["BCost"].Value = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["LandingCost"].Value) / (Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["GSTRate"].Value) / 100 + 1), 2);


                    row.Cells["BCostAmt"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["BCost"].Value) * Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["OrderQty"].Value);

                    row.Cells["GSTAmt"].Value = Math.Round((Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["BCostAmt"].Value) * (Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["GSTRate"].Value) / 100)), 2);

                    row.Cells["NetAmt"].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["BCostAmt"].Value) + Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["GSTAmt"].Value);

                    txtPOProdQtyReq.Clear();

                    txtPOTotalItems.Text = Convert.ToString(rowIndex + 1);


                    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridPOItems.Columns)
                    {
                        txtPOTotalQty.Text = dataGridPOItems.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Sum(r => Convert.ToDecimal(r.Cells[4].Value)).ToString();
                        txtPOTCost.Text = dataGridPOItems.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Sum(r => Convert.ToDecimal(r.Cells[12].Value)).ToString();
                        txtPOTAX.Text = dataGridPOItems.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Sum(r => Convert.ToDecimal(r.Cells[10].Value)).ToString();

                    }

                    ClassControlsHandler.ClearAll(this.groupProdInfo);
                    txtPOProdID.Focus();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
```

Expected Results: i just want to add new rows in updateMode.

Thank You.

Comment: Message is pretty clear.  Edit and add rows to the DataTable instead, the grid will automatically show them since it is connected to it.

Comment: Or, add the DataTable to a `BindingSource.DatatSource` and use the BindingSource as the DGV DataSource. It will allow to add rows to the DataTable directly from the DataGridView (adding data to the New Row (last row), for example).

Comment: @Jimi Sir, Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it like this?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Product ID";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Product Name";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Product Price";

            string[] row = new string[] { "1", "Product 1", "1000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "2", "Product 2", "2000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "3", "Product 3", "3000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            row = new string[] { "4", "Product 4", "4000" };
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
}
```

http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-add-column.htm

Or, simply.

```
private void InsertNewRowToDGV()
  {
   //we have to get the index of a last row id:
   int index = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count;

   //and count +1 to get a new row id:
   index++;
   this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple: instead of directly using a [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Data.DataTable);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) as the `DataGridView.DataSource`, you can use a [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) and set the `DataTable` as the `BindingSource.DataSource`.

The `BindingSource` will then become the `DataGridView.DataSource`.

```
private BindingSource dgvBindingSource = null;
```

Create a `DataTable` with the required `Columns` or fill it using a [DataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter?view=netframework-4.7.2), then:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("TableName");
//Set the Columns or fill it with a DataAdapter

dgvBindingSource = new BindingSource();
dgvBindingSource.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.DataSource = dgvBindingSource;
dt.Dispose();
```

When you need to add a new [DataRow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Data.DataRow);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) to the `BindingSource`, you can use the `BindingSource.DataSource` directly - the Fields must be provided in the correct order:

```
(dgvBindingSource.DataSource as DataTable).Rows.Add(new object[] {
    [Field1 Value], [Field2 Value], [Field3 Value], [Field N Value]
});
```

or add a new `DataRow` and assign the Fields values using the `Columns` names:

```
using (DataTable dt = (dgvBindingSource.DataSource as DataTable))
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row["Column0"] = SomeValue1;
    row["Column1"] = SomeValue2;
    row["Column2"] = SomeValue3;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Both methods will updated the DataGridView immediately.