# Gridview removing previous record when trying to add new record

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have 1 windows form with 1 textbox where user will type ProductId, press enter key and based on that I want to add records to my gridview.

Now the problem is old records gets removed when I search new product id so I always have only 1 record in my gridview based on my last search.

**So for eg :** If user have search for Product Id = 1 for the first time,then it is added to grid.Now when User try to add another product Product Id = 2, than Product Id = 1 is removed and now I see only Product ID = 2 record in gridview

Code :

```
public partial class ProductScan : Form
{
    private BindingSource grdProductListBindingSource = new BindingSource();
    public ProductScan()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ProductScan_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grdProductList.DataSource =  grdProductListBindingSource;
    }

    private void txtProductId_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            string pathName = txtFilePath.Text;
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(txtFilePath.Text);
            DataTable tbContainer = new DataTable();
            string strConn = string.Empty;
            string sheetName = fileName;

            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(pathName);
            if (!file.Exists) { throw new Exception("Error, file doesn't exists!"); }
            string extension = file.Extension;

            switch (extension)
            {
                case ".xls":
                        strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
                        break;
                case ".xlsx":
                        strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
                        break;
                default:
                        strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
                        break;
            }
            string fieldSelector = "[ProductID], [ProductName], [MRP] ";
            string query = $"SELECT {fieldSelector} FROM [{sheetName}$A1:F15535] WHERE [ProductID] = {Convert.ToInt32(txtProductId.Text)}";
            using (OleDbConnection cnnxls = new OleDbConnection(strConn))
                using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, cnnxls))
                {
                    oda.Fill(tbContainer);
                    grdProductListBindingSource.DataSource = tbContainer;
                    grdProductList.AutoResizeColumns(
                            DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
                }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

I have taken reference from here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control

Whats the problem here ?

Comment: Every time the `KeyUp` fires, you assign a new `DataSource` the your gridview, with only the row(s) for the given `ProductID`. So its normal behaviour. If you dont want that, dont keep assiging a new datasource to your grid, but append to the existing one

Comment: @GuidoG But I am creating instance of BindingSource at the beginning of the form so it should refer to the existing one right?

Comment: You are assigning a new datasource to your BindingSource every time again, so it looses all prior values each time. If you want to retain prior values, dont do `grdProductListBindingSource.DataSource = tbContainer` each time, but append all rows from `tbContainer` to `grdProductListBindingSource.DataSource`

Comment: In other words, you have a coupled a BindingSource to your grid, and that does not changes. But where this BindingSource gets its data, that you overwrite each time. You should append to it, not re-assign it

Comment: Told you. Follow the simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55146669/7444103). **Add** the new data to the `BindingSource.DataSource` object as shown.

Comment: In the example of @Jimi they do `Rows.Add()` so they append data to an existing list. What you do is reassign the list each time